# Jquery html() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put the `html` markup into my `array` with the following codes

```
//my htmlData which is entered by user so it could be varies.
<em>test</em> here for the testing purpose
second line <strong>texts</strong> here
```

I want to store them in my `array` by using

```
var data = [];
$(htmlData).contents().each(function(){
           data.push($(this).html().trim());
     }
```

but I got an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trim' of null.`

Not sure why `$(this).html()` would returns a `null`.

Can anyone help me here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be the issue with the `text nodes.` As they do not have the `innerHTML` property
Try filtering them out

```
var data = [];
$(htmlData).contents().each(function(){
     var nodeType = this.nodeType;
     if(nodeType === 1) { // Will only select element nodes
        data.push($.trim($(this).html()));
     } 
     else if(nodeType === 3) {
        data.push($.trim(this.nodeValue));
     }
}
```

You can use `.nodeValue` to access the data of th etext node

Comment: thanks but your codes will only keep the markup texts but remove plain texts that users enter. +1

Comment: @FlyingCat Based on this you can push something different (nodeValue or textContent) depending if the node type is element or not.

Comment: @FlyingCat .. You can use `nodeValue` to read the content of the text node

Comment: @Sushanth I have a follow up question. Is that possible I can store texts with html markup into data array? what I have now only test but not <em>test</em>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $(htmlData).contents() returns a valid jQuery object, use $.trim($(this).html()) instead of .trim()

Answer (score 0):

Text nodes don't have `innerHTML` properties.