# How to store html markup to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following question from my last post.

[Jquery html() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755884/jquery-html-issue#17755907)

I want to store each `node` as `full html markup`.

The `data` array should be something like

```
['<em>test</em>', 'here for the testing purpose',
'second line', '<strong>texts</strong>', 'here']
```

The codes I have now:

```
if(this.nodeType === 3) { // Will only select element nodes
    data.push($(this).text());
}else if(this.nodeType === 1){
    data.push($(this).html());
}
```

but it only store

```
['test', 'here for the testing purpose','texts','here']
```

Is it possible to store the html `markup` as well?

Thanks so much!

Comment: array in js are `[...]` not `(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
data.push($(this).html());
```

with

```
data.push(this.outerHTML);
```

Remember

`this`  -- DOM object

`$(this)` -- jQuery Object

Try using `DOM` objects instead of `jQuery` objects whenever possible as the former are a bit faster, because it eliminates an extra overhead of converting them to latter and then apply a method..  Should not be a big deal but just for info.

Answer (score 2):

[`element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) returns the markup including the outer tags of the element:

```
data.push(this.outerHTML);
```